# how i can run function of UIbutton without clicking the button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, action

Here is my code:

```
-(void)btnSelectItem:(id)sender{

    NSString *userId =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:USER_ID_KEY];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_selected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    int i = (int)[sender tag];
    //[CollectionViewSize performBatchUpdates:^{ [CollectionViewSize reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]]; } completion:nil];



   // [CollectionViewSize reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i section:0]]];

    strMenuID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arayResponce objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"menu_id"]];
    lblItemCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arayResponce objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"price"]];
    [adCartParam removeAllObjects];

    adCartParam = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [adCartParam setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kresto_id] forKey:@"resto_id"];
    [adCartParam setObject:strMenuID forKey:@"menu_id"];
    [adCartParam setObject:userId forKey:@"cust_id"];
    [adCartParam setObject:[AppDelegate getDelegate].subCategoryID forKey:@"cat_id"];

    NSString  *price = [CommonClass stringByReplacing:lblItemCount.text and:@"$" withString:@""];

    ///[lblItemCount.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$"
                                                                    // withString:@""];
    [adCartParam setObject:price forKey:@"price"];

    [adCartParam setObject:@1 forKey:@"qty"];
    [adCartParam setObject:[[arayResponce objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"size_id"] forKey:@"size_id"];



}
```

Comment: You can do with `[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: call this btnSelectItem method in viewdidload.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //if you need the highlight   
 [button setHighlighted:YES];
 [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

[self btnSelectItem:yourButton];

Answer (score 0):

first you change `-(void)btnSelectItem:(id)sender` with `-(void)btnSelectItem:(UIButton*)sender` 
and then call it from any method. with `[self btnSelectItem:yourButtonOutlet]`